# UML generation from RUBY code

Tags: linux, osx, uml, reverse-engineering, ruby

I am looking for UML tool that gives some features of reverse engineering ruby source code. I am currently using Visual Paradigm which seems the best choice for working with ruby till now, but …

- no reverse engineering for ruby
- RoR is not supported
- Price-wise it is too expensive

Comment: Welcome to SR! Other than RoR support & reverse engineering what features do you want/need? Also instead of saying Visual Paradigm is too expensive better to say what is an acceptable price range.